# Does Firebase server sdk works on Google Appengine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On Firebase server setup page (https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup), it provides a java sdk (firebase-server-sdk.jar) for regular Java application.  i'm wondering if firebase-server-sdk.jar will work for google appengine.

As you know, google appengine is special container that have restriction such as not allowing us to run our own long running process.

firebase-server-sdk allows us to setup listeners to listen to data change on firebase realtime database, which seems like it may require some kind of long running process.  (for example, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/retrieve-data)

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen for app engine it is necessary to set manual scaling and use only one instance, it is not enough for production. Is there a way to use firebase with automatic scaling?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yevgen thank you very much for the answer.  so the answer is firebase-server-sdk works with google appengine java, but only on manual scaling as it requires a long-running thread.  unfortunately, we would prefer to use automatic scaling.  it might be nice to have 2 types of sdk.  1 sdk that works on automatic scaling appengine, but it only allows read once (does not allow listener that listens to the change).  Since one-time read does not require long-running thread, it might works on automatic scaling.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback both! We're aware that the way the Firebase Java SDK currently works on App Engine doesn't cover the ideal usage of App Engine. We're always looking at ways to improve, but currently this is not being worked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @FrankvanPuffelen for the answer.

At the current moment, firebase-server-sdk works with google appengine java, but only on manual scaling instance. as it requires a long-running thread.  It does not work for appengine on auto-scaling.

source: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at the flexible environment of appEngine.

Standard version is not prepared at all for persistent connections (is more usefull when we talk about periodic maintenance of the db, mails, or anything you can actually do with a cron) and if you try to use it permanently sometimes it  will lose connection.

So if this is your case, consider using flexible environment. It's beta, probably it will be more expensive, but it keeps the connection up.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/

hope this helps!